# Ansible kitchen test fails executing source command on debian

Tags: python, rspec, ansible, test-kitchen

I wrote a ansible playbook role for python and trying to test it using kitchen test with Serverspec/RSpec. The following test is making sure if I am able source activate the virtualenv. This runs fine on CentOS but test fails on Debian-Ubuntu with an error (check below the code block)

```
  describe command("source #{jenkins_home}/virtualenv/#{version}/bin/activate") do
    its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }
  end
```

Error:

```
 6) Command "source /home/jenkins/virtualenv/pypy3/bin/activate" exit_status should eq 0
    Failure/Error: its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }

      expected: 0
           got: 127

      (compared using ==)
      /bin/sh -c source\ /home/jenkins/virtualenv/pypy3/bin/activate

    # /tmp/verifier/suites/serverspec/python_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**MY ASSUMPTION**

Its trying to run from **/bin/sh** which basically cant run **source** command. How can I mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the call from `source` to `.`?  That should work in both `bash` and `sh`.

Comment: you are a genius! period !